# Why did I get so little experience from a huge massacre?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm playing Nightmare mode right now and I had gotten a 45 massacre kill, one of the bigger ones I have gotten, especially on Nightmare. Only problem was that I only got +40 bonus experience.

Why in the world would I get so little experience for so many kills?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You only get experience from the bonus for enemies that give experience as normal kills. Summoned, resurrected, or low level enemies do not give experience, and therefore would count towards a massacre bonus, but would not contribute to the experience bonus.

Comment: Guess that makes sense then, I was trying to kill a bunch of those yellow robed guys, and they had one of those yellow glowing monsters in a shield that kept summoning those weird crawling monsters.